# Can I set arbitrary attributes to file in iOS?

Tags: ios, file

I'm implementing some code that manages simple files (like text files), and I would like to add some information to the file, like, for example, location, tags, etc, without writing extra text on the text file.

I think that the easiest way to do this would be to add extra info to the file attributes, but I'm not sure if that is possible.

I've been playing with NSURL's `setResourceValue:forKey:error:`, but it seems that only the NSURL's predefined keys actually write something to the attributes of the file. So:

```
NSURL *fileURL; //suppose this points to something
NSError *error;
id resourceValue;

[fileURL setResourceValue:@"recorded string" forKey:@"testingkey" error:&error];
[fileURL getResourceValue:&resourceValue forKey:@"testingkey" error:&error];
```

In the code above, both functions `setResourceValue:forKey:error:` and `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` return `YES` meaning they were successful, but the final value of `resourceValue` is nil, which might mean that the value was actually not recorded.

So, is there a way of setting my own attributes to files in iOS? If not, what would be a good (easy) way of assimilating extra information to files, without modifying the files themselves?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is all you need:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/03/reading-and-writing-extended-file-attributes/

Comment: Thanks! That indeed is all I need.

Comment: @Marcelo I am getting output from this code after setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplement for this question:[extended-file-attributes](http://nshipster.com/extended-file-attributes/)

This articles analyzes in detail about how to solve the problem which is not only need not change the original files content but also write some info into the files.

you can use like this:

```
#include <sys/xattr.h>

    if (!&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) {
        // iOS <= 5.0.1
        const char *filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
        const char *name = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t value = 1;
        int result = setxattr(filePath, name, &value, sizeof(value), 0, 0);
    } else {
        // iOS >= 5.1
        NSError *error = nil;
        [URL setResourceValue:@YES
                       forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                        error:&error];
    }
```